# Editing Font and Color On Script

Tags: asp-classic

My script displays all the images that are in a folder. On the 1st page it displays a list of all the folders. I want to change the font to verdana and the color to black. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

```
<%
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

qfolder = request.querystring("f")
if qfolder = "" then
    folderspec = server.mappath(".")
    Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set demofolder = filesys.GetFolder(folderspec) 
    Set folcoll = demofolder.SubFolders
    For Each subfol in folcoll
        folsize = left((subfol.size/1000000), 3)
        folist = folist & "<a href='?f=" & subfol.name & "'><strong title='view'></strong> " & subfol.Name & "" & vbcrlf
        folist = folist & "<BR>"  
    Next
    set filesys = nothing
    Response.Write folist

else

filepath = server.mappath(".") & "\" & qfolder
captionfile = filepath & "\captions.txt"
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim SomeArray()
'caption part
    If filesys.FileExists(captionfile) then
        set file = filesys.GetFile(captionfile)
        Set TextStream = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading,TristateUseDefault)
        captioncount = 0
        Do While Not TextStream.AtEndOfStream
            Line = TextStream.readline
            ReDim Preserve SomeArray(captioncount)
            SomeArray(captioncount) = line
            'response.write captioncount & " " & somearray(captioncount) & ""
            captioncount = captioncount + 1
            'Response.write Line
        Loop
        textStream.close
    end if

'folder part
    Set demofolder = filesys.GetFolder(filepath) 
    Set filecoll = demofolder.Files
    filecount = 0
    For Each file in filecoll
        Ext = UCase(Right(File.Path, 3)) 
        If Ext = "JPG" OR Ext = "GIF" OR Ext = "PNG" Then
        on error resume next
        data = SomeArray(filecount)
        on error goto 0
        hrefpath = qfolder & "/" & file.name
        imagepath = "<strong>" & data & "</strong><a href='" & hrefpath & "' title='free image gallery' border=0><img width=200 height=150 src='" & hrefpath & "' border='" & border_size & "' title=""" & data & """ style='border-color: " & border_color & ";'></a>"
        filist = filist & imagepath & vbcrlf
        filist = filist & ""
        filecount = filecount + 1
        data = ""
        end if
    Next
    set filesys = Nothing
    filist = filist & "<small><a href='http://www.allscoop.com/' target='_blank'></a></small>"
%>

<h3><a href="." title="Back"><img src="arrow.jpg" alt="Back" height="16" width="20" /></a>
&nbsp;<%=qfolder%></h3>

<p><%=filist%></p>

<% end if %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's just css/html...

```
<style>
a {
    font-family:Verdana;
    color: #000000;
}
</style>
```

that makes all links black and verdana...